# Make a music server with server and client side in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, audio-player

I want to do my first project in NodeJs. Basically I want to perform a music server on one side and a client to play music stored on the server. The whole will run only in a local private network.

I have only beginner skills as I just read one book about nodeJs, so I know how to initiate a site with Express, use a mongoDB database with mongoose and some other things.

My issue is that I don't know how to begin my project. As I see the things :

- my server will host the music files (mp3 and flac). In a first time this will done through real files, nothing will be stored in any database
- in a first time my clients will have to be able to list those files and play them.

But in a first time I'm just not able to find a library to play music files, it's just a mess as there are so many of them that I don't know what to choose.

So if you can help me to choose one and architecture my project, this would be a great help. thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you're going to do but you just need html5 to play an audio file.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer ! is html5 mandatory ? no other way to do it ? usage of any node package ?

Comment: @MrFlo Node only exists on the server. The server might be in California; the client device might be a cellphone in Venezuela. The server just sends the data to the browser; it's the browser's job to operate on the data. While you're running the server on the same machine, the paradigm doesn't change. The browser requests data from the server as if it's on a different planet. No server-side NodeJS library is going to help play the file on the user's browser. You need to point `express.static` at a folder full of MP3s, you need a media player on the webpage (or build your own, using `<audio>`).

Comment: @MrFlo That, of course, is the most-basic solution; content streaming / seeking, playlists, metadata, file-uploads, sound-visualization, EQ, panning, virtualized surround-sound...  ...all of them are possible. If you had the raw tracks of each instrument, real surround sound could be possible in certain versions of certain browsers.  Start by looking up how the `<audio controls src="/music/song.mp3"></audio>` solution would work for you, and how you can change the source, to play different songs.

Comment: as you explain it, this makes sense, thanks. But this means that I would only need a `express.static` on the server, and that the client-site would do the whole work, right ? in any case i gonna test your suggestion with the `<audio>`.